# IWebElement.Submit "Submits this element to webserver"?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The documentation is a bit unclear on this.

I use the simple browser web driver.

The code goes like this:

```
var url = "http://foo.bar/Login.aspx";

var browser = new SimpleBrowserDriver();

browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

var loginBox = browser.FindElement(By.Name("loginbox"));
loginBox.SendKeys("test@hotmail.com");

loginBox.Submit();
```

and when I hover the Submit word, I can read that the method submits the element to the webserver.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `submit()` on the element, `selenium` would find the element's parent form and submit it - find the `input` with `type="submit"` and click it. This is basically a convenient shortcut since you can call `submit()` on any element inside the `form`.

Alternatively, you can find that input by your own and click on it.

See also:

- [Selenium Webdriver submit() vs click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click)

Comment: Ok, input.getForm().submit() would be a great way to make my life easy. Thanks for the answer.