# Selenium HtmlUnitDriver Login to Website

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, nosuchelementexception, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to use an HtmlUnitDriver to login to [marketwatch.com](http://www.marketwatch.com/game/). I don't think the program is ever getting past the login prompt, and I did check that I have the correct email and password...

Thank you so much for trying to help me!

Here's my commented code:

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        log.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        // Go to marketwatch
        driver.get("http://www.marketwatch.com/game/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); // prints 'Virtual Stock Exchange Games (VSE) - MarketWatch.com'
        // Click on 'login'
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("profilelogin"));
        login.click();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); // prints 'Log In'
        // Enter username and password
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        email.sendKeys(Ref.EMAIL);
        WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        pass.sendKeys(Ref.PASSWORD);
        // Click submit button
        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton"));
        submit.click();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); // prints 'Log In' (same title as before we tried to log in)
        // Try to find 
        WebElement game = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='maincontent']/section[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a"));
        // This gets printed to console:
        // Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //*[@id='maincontent']/section[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a
        // I don't think it's ever getting past the login screen...
        // You don't really have to read past this, unless you think I might've messed something else up and you want to fix it.
        game.click();
        WebElement trade = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='vse-nav']/ul/li[2]/a"));
        trade.click();
        WebElement searchBar = driver.findElement(By.className("instrumentsearch ac_input unused"));
        searchBar.sendKeys("GOOG");
        searchBar.submit();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable javascript, the website needs it:

```
    // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

You can enable JavaScript by doing this way as well:

```
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This is sorta an old post, but I think I remember that being the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After your submit.click() you can do a dump of the current DOM of the selenium-attached browser that you can examine to determine what Selenium is actually encountering. Doing so via the following code may allow you to view any applicable error messages...maybe there's an error stating that robots aren't allowed to access the site, for example.

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Comment: What would I look for in the page source to tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Looking into it. In the meantime, you may wish to remove your password from the linked post on line 91. I'll not attempt the login with it, but do confirm that it is as expected.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize my password was in there. Thank you so much for pointing that out!

Comment: First thoughts: Since the DOM pasted is pulled after Submit is clicked, I would not expect it to contain the filled-out information for username and password that your paste contains. Due to this, I suspect the submission did not occur. Perhaps it is not happening, perhaps it is only that we pulled the info too quickly (after the submit click, but before refresh actually occurred. I'd suggest that you wait for the staleness of the submit button before running the getPageSource() and then re-examine.

Comment: Are you telling me to do something like 'Thread.sleep(5000);' or is there an actual "staleness" check of some sort? I'll just wait for 5 seconds for now...

Comment: (pseudo code)
To wait for that staleness, you can use:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(submit);
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
Examine to see if the page had changed. The 30 second wait should be sufficient but may need increasing. Please advise if this has helped.

Comment: Okay I'll give this a try

Comment: On the note of wait'ing and ExpectedConditions, you may wish to familiarize yourself these:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Comment: Alright I'll check those out... also it timed out so I'll let it go longer than 30 seconds, maybe there's something else going on...? Also thank you so much for like, having a conversation with me. You're super helpful

Comment: Okay I let it go for 60 seconds and it still timed out, here's  the code
http://pastebin.com/52Tgj848

Comment: If the timeout occurs after being given ample time, then there's an issue with the submission of the form. 
To work around this, we may want to attempt usage of the Selenium provided .submit() method. This can be called from any form element. This means that you can use it on the already-referenced password WebElement, and eliminate the location and clicking of the submit button altogether. See [this question for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click)

Comment: Code looks as expected. Attempt the .submit mentioned above.

Comment: I got: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot locate element used to submit form -------  I'll go and read the other question haha

Comment: As an aside, I see the DOM has the "Keep me logged in" checkbox enabled. This means that once succesfully logged in, the script will fail because you will not get the login page any longer. I'd suggest unchecking it via the script and opting to always login. 
                  <input type="checkbox" name="savelogin" id="savelogin" checked="checked" class="login_checkbox" value="on"/>

Comment: What'd you mean unchecking it via the script? Sorry if it seems like I don't really know anything...

Comment: See http://seleniumcodes.blogspot.com/2011/10/checking-and-unchecking-checkbox.html?m=1

Comment: Okay I added this (http://pastebin.com/UBUT4zAN) right before we create the "login" element. Then got a NoSuchElementException when I attempted to run it. It couldn't find something with id="savelogin"