# Selenium - Different pages displaying with respect to submit() and click() method in [a link]

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I was trying to submit incorrect sensitive information to the login fields with `submit()` method instead of click button event. Due to this I am getting a reset password page. where as if I perform click event on login button I am getting login page seeking sensitive information again. Why I am getting different page for `submit()` and click `method()`. Any help would be appreciated. snippet of code which I tried to submit the sensitive information using `submit()` method is given below. Thanks in advance.

```
List<WebElement> inputFields = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
for (int i = 0; i < inputFields.size(); i++) {   
    inputFields.get(i).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
    if (inputFields.get(i).getAttribute("type").equalsIgnoreCase("password")) {
       inputFields.get(i).sendKeys("test@1234");
       inputFields.get(i).submit();
       break;
   }
}
```

URL: https://www.ymlp.com/login.html

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This post might explain the difference in behavior: [Selenium Webdriver submit() vs click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click)

As far as fixing it, I'd suggest just using the click() method.

Comment: i understood the difference but how two pages are getting displayed for each event. how does submit() method invoke a webpage ?