# Submit() redirects to another page, while click() not allowing me to access the inner page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone explain me the exact difference between submit() and click()

Like my scenario is i want to access this [site](https://www.ymlp.com/login.html). when i click on login button using `click()` method. Site is not allowing me to access the inner page, while using `submit()` method, Site is redirect to the another page.

So, i'm not getting the proper difference between these two methods. Refer below code snippet for more details.

```
driver.get("https://www.ymlp.com/login.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();    
driver.findElement(By.id("T1")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("T2")).sendKeys("test@1234");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginbtn")).submit();
```

When you execute above code site redirects to another page,  Now while just changing the last line of code as below mentioned code, site is not allowing me to access the inner page.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("loginbtn")).click();
```

Can anyone help me on this issue? I would like to know that why click() is not working well here.

Best Regards.

Comment: might be duplicate of this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click

Comment: It's not duplicate question, I have provided the site url, along with my code snippet. but both methods behaving differently here. can you explain me why click() is not working well on above mentioned site?

Comment: add wait before click method. sometime click method execute with knowing button is clickable or not.

Comment: Try with wait, but not work well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Even when you click on the button manually, it doesn't work**. This could be an application issue. As far as Submit() is concerned, it can be used for the buttons inside the form tag. Basically you are trying to submit the form.

If you carefully look at the HTML, when you click on the button, the class value changes to **"btn btn-secondary preload isLocked"** and in the back end if you go the the Network tab in the console window and analyse the login.js, they have a function

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#T1").focus();$(".removeerrorontype").keypress(function(){$(this).removeClass("error");});$("#loginbtn").click(function(e){if($(this).hasClass("isLocked")){return false;}
```

So, I feel the above condition returns false and hence it doesn't move further. **"isLocked"** is making some difference here.

Answer (score 1):

`submit()` method is applicable not to some particular `button` or `input` field, but to ancestor `<form>` element

It works like bellow (this is `Python` code, but point should be the same):

```
element_in_form = driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_ANY_element_inside_form') # this might be any locator, not only id
form = element_in_form.find_element_by_xpath("./ancestor-or-self::form")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].submit()", form)
```

There is no difference what is `element_in_form` (username input, password input, login button...) as long as it present inside `<form>`.

`Forgot Username/password?` link also located inside same form and for some reason by using `submit()` you actually trigger not the `Login` button, but `Forgot Username/password?` link clicking...

I can just guess that this is developers' mistake

Answer (score 0):

Both click() and submit() works in a same way except submit() looks for forms.

You can use .click() method to click on any button.There is no restriction for click buttons.
 That means element's type = "button" or type = "submit", .click() method will works for both.
 If button is inside  tag or button is outside  tag, the click() method will work.

.submit() method is used for only submit form after click on button.
That means element's type = "submit" and button should be inside  tag, then only submit() will work.

In your case, why click is not working could be not specific to the submit() or click() I guess

Answer (score 0):

Try Following: Worked for me (I guess)

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();    
driver.findElement(By.id("T1")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("T2")).sendKeys("test@1234");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("loginbtn"))));
System.out.println("Is Visible");
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("loginbtn"))));
System.out.println("Is clickable");

driver.findElement(By.id("loginbtn")).click();
```

Comment: Hello @Kushal, I have tried your code, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I tried the same code; it was able to click the button as it give me error because of incorrect credentials. Did you try with real creds?

Comment: Have your tried with `driver.findElement(By.id("loginbtn")).submit(); ` then compare the behaviour of click and submit method.

Comment: hmm.. If you just use the click() button it highlights username and password in red; but if I use submit() then It asks for email for password reset.

Comment: What happens when you provide real creds amnually for click?

Comment: Exactly, Now you understand my question properly. :)

Comment: What happens when you provide real creds?