# How to click on this button with Selenium but the id is not unique

Tags: selenium

```
<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 layerConfirm uiOverlayButton _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy" type="submit">Confirm</button>
```

The above is the html code for a button on Facebook page. I would like help in selenium web driver to click on this button but the id of the tag is changing on every refresh

[Code on facebook website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGL4h.png)

Thank you all for your help but I have solved this one with help from you all people and trial and error.

Comment: Where is `id` in this button tag ?

Comment: The id is coming from the previous line in code which is changing everytime the page refreshes

Comment: You can find the button by text if you want `page_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Confirm']").click()`

Comment: You can use `submit()` to submit `form` without clicking the button

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your solution but the text is not being identified and I have tried this earlier too

Comment: @Andersson could you give me the code for it?

Comment: @Vishesh-gupta, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click)

Comment: Can you consider showcasing your work and relevant HTML DOM please? It's a clear case of overlay, @TrimantraSoftwareSolution Answer should work. Try to be precise with the `ExpectedConditions`. Thanks

Comment: @Andersson thank you very much that helped. i would use it in my oother codes. I didn't read that one properly so I made a big mistake and realize it now. That makes total sense

Comment: @DebanjanB thank you for your comment but as per Andersson's post which I just read properly it works now

Answer (score 1):

Use `ExplicitWait` until visibility of your element and then perform click

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit'][normalize-space()='Confirm']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit'][normalize-space()='Confirm']")).click();
```

Another solution can be if some javascript preventing you to click the button then use below `JavascriptExecutor` code and let me know if any issue

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit'][normalize-space()='Confirm']"));
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;    
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: Thank you but I got another way of solving my problem which is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fixed class names for this

```
driver.findElement(By.className("layerConfirm"));
```

Or combination

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".layerConfirm.uiOverlayButton"));
```

If the dynamic id has fixed part you can use partial id

```
// id=someid134313
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id*='someid']"));
```

Or by the "Confirm" text

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Confirm')]"));
```

Comment: In the last one, when I use .Click() operation, it says element not visible

Answer (score 0):

As Facebook element's class and id are dynamic, you will have trouble automating further with Selenium.

In this case you can go with xpath

```
//button[@type='submit' and text()='Confirm']
```

or

```
//button[text()='Confirm']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath for your case:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Confirm')]")).click();
```

Hope it will help you.