# How do I insert hidden input into html button with python selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium's WebDriver and coding in Python.

There's a button 'submit' on a HTML which I am trying to click using my script. However the source code shows that it the button has a hidden ID input:

```
<html><head>
<title>Creating ID</title></head>

<style>
p {font-size: 12pt }
</style>
<body>
<p>Your ID is going to be created. Please press the submitt button</p>
<form action=atmos.cgi method=get><p>
<input type=hidden name=ID value=202.166.76.23.deY7hZxSeq>
<input type=submit />
</form>
</body></html>
```

The html page looks like this:

[image]

How do I go about 'clicking' the button?

Comment: What did you try? what was the problem with it?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to start to key in any inputs..or what I am supposed to do with this given source code

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Do I have to input the hidden value?

Comment: I don't understand what *input the hidden value* means. I suggest you do some research and try few things. Questions without any effort are not accepted well in SO.

Comment: Sorry, can I ask what is the element that I am supposed to be looking for in this case?

Comment: If you are using Selenium probably you don't need that hidden value input because is self-generated by the page. You need to learn how to use selenium, but I Think SO is not the place for that.

Comment: The `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NishantThakur 's answer should solve your question as the `<input>` tag with type as **submit** is separate from the `<input>` tag with type as **hidden**. Additionally as the `<input>` tag with type as **submit** is located within the following `<form>` :

```
<form action=atmos.cgi method=get>
```

To click on the element with type as **submit** you can use either of the following lines of code :

- Using `click()` :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@action='atmos.cgi']//input[@type='submit']")).click();
  ```
- Using `submit()` :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@action='atmos.cgi']//input[@type='submit']")).submit();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to click the Submit button then following hidden input element is of no concern to you:

```
<input type=hidden name=ID value=202.166.76.23.deY7hZxSeq>
```

Submit button element is represented by:

```
<input type=submit />
```

Following is sample code in Java. Python should be similar:

```
WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
submitButton.click();
```