# Selenium Connection Issue possible form action issue?

Tags: selenium, timeout

We have one website (third party software), that I am only having issues with. I am getting the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The only thing different with this button than other buttons in this software/site and others is this form action.

```
<form action="https://test.xxxxxxxxxx.org/customer/account/createpost/" method="post" id="form-validate" class="scaffold-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It clocks and waits and returns the above message....but the form has been submitted and continues to the next screen, but Selenium loses it. I have no idea if that form action has anything to do with it, but anything outside of it, will not lose control.

Any way to work around this? Anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the form action. I had to change it from a "Click" action to a submit. I found it from this link

[Selenium Webdriver submit() vs click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click/23231894)

Sorry..I have been doing this lately. I ask a question and it prompts me to look up the question in a different way that garners different result, and that is what happened this time.

Comment: That's a good part of the reason why the SO rules around questions exist. It forces you to do research and then document it in such a way that others can understand it... which many times leads to you finding the answer to your own question. :)