# Why Python Selenium click button doesnt work on Amazon

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make amazon item buyer but there is one problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\QP\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.tr/gp/product/9750748468?pf_rd_r=NCJRXGDB60BMBAWHZB0K&pf_rd_p=dbef927e-126e-4d59-a744-316eb26cc421&pd_rd_r=081be57a-efdb-4f6b-b282-72fb528b1bc5&pd_rd_w=Avc97&pd_rd_wg=XdzTG&ref_=pd_gw_unk")
try:
    element=driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-stack")
    element.click()
    print("Item found")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Item doesnt exist")
```

Actually selenium found item because except doesnt work and i saw "Item found" on console but element.click() doesnt work.When i make same process on another web sites it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept cookies first
`driver.find_element_by_id("sp-cc-accept").click()`

Comment: Tnx but before your solution i changed element.submit() instead of element.clicked() and i worked.Why it worked ? I didnt accept cookies.

Comment: because it's in form element [link](https://www.guru99.com/accessing-forms-in-webdriver.html) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click)

since you didn't explain error I guessed it was intercepted by that cookie banner. click should also work

Comment: Tnx for answers guys.And i have one more question how can i select multiple class python selenium.I looked for on ınternet but i didnt fount solution.

Comment: what do you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: it didnt work.i check "sp-cc-accept" with ctrl+f in browser inpect and no result comes out

Comment: can you try to open page in incognito? maybe you already accepted it so it doesn't show up anymore.. but if it worked for you with .submit() you don't need this step

Comment: i changed chrome account and it fixed tnx for answers guys @ble